# How to change or delete the start page of a UWP application at launching

Tags: c#, uwp, start-page

I am new to UWP C #.
When I launch my UWP application, I have the Windows blue image.

How do I change or delete it?
OS Windows 10 (1809) Visual Studio C #

Comment: do you mean the splash screen ? you can check this then : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/add-a-splash-screen

Answer (score 0):

You're Referring to the Splash Screen

Here's the Official Doc on how to do it

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/add-a-splash-screen

If you want to change the Starting Page for a UWP application

in the App.xaml.cs

Look for the line with:

```
rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage)
```

Just change MainPage to whatever page you want to start on.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Fall Creators Update (1709), the splash screen is optional. You can use [the `uap5:Optional` attribute of the `uap:SplashScreen` element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-uap-splashscreen) to disable the splash screen (assuming your app starts fast enough).